# WARN: HHH90000028: Support for `<hibernate-mappings/>` is deprecated hibernate log

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

This is the complete log message:

> WARN: HHH90000028: Support for `<hibernate-mappings/>` is deprecated [RESOURCE : resources/hibernate-configs/hibernate-mappings/mappings.hbm.xml]; migrate to orm.xml or mapping.xml, or enable `hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled` for on the fly transformation

I've tried to look for solutions on the internet. However, articles regarding this log message are scarce. I found this github page which is part of hibernate:
[DeprecationLogger.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/log/DeprecationLogger.java)

This part of the source code peaks my interest

```
/**
 * Different from {@link #deprecatedSetting} in that sometimes there is no
 * direct alternative
 */
@LogMessage(level = WARN)
@Message(
        id = 90000028,
        value = "Support for `<hibernate-mappings/>` is deprecated [%s : %s]; " +
                "migrate to orm.xml or mapping.xml, or enable `" + AvailableSettings.TRANSFORM_HBM_XML +
                "` for on the fly transformation"
)
void logDeprecatedHbmXmlProcessing(SourceType sourceType, String name);
```

Although, I still couldn't come up with a solution.

My questions are:

- How to migrate to orm.xml or mapping.xml?
- How to enable `hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enabling `hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled`**
This works by adding a config property to persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml, just like every other configuration is made for Hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled">true</property>
```

*N.B. The transformer is not complete yet. As time of writing, you could face errors like: `Could not parse mapping document: META-INF/YourClass.hbm.xml (RESOURCE). OneToMany transformation not yet implemented.`*

**Migration to orm.xml or mapping.xml**
Migration to orm.xml (the JPA standard mapping) or mapping.xml (the JPA standard + Hibernate mapping extensions) can be done with the [Hibernate Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.hibernate.orm) or manually. Since this is a one time task, I would recommend that you setup a dedicated Gradle project to do the migration.

Comment: How to do migration in maven? Btw I successfully added 'hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled' in my cfg.xml file. In my previous attempts, for some reason, I couldn't put it in my cfg.xml file.

Comment: Update: everytime I put 'hibernate.transform_hbm_xml.enabled' in my cfg.xml file, I receive this error: org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document: resources/hibernate-configs/hibernate-mappings/mappings.hbm.xml (RESOURCE)

Comment: Please share your cfg.xml then please

Comment: I'm having a hard time putting my cfg.xml content in my post. You can view my cfg.xml file content in this pastebin: https://controlc.com/90b3878b

Comment: Well, for some reason, Hibernate can't find the file given by the path `resources/hibernate-configs/hibernate-mappings/mappings.hbm.xml` on the class path. What is your project structure or how does the final JAR file look like? The path you are configuring must be the relative path from within the JAR file to the file.

Comment: I assume the error would be MappingNotFoundException if a mapping resource can't be found. I'm new to hibernate so I'm not sure if I'm correct. I'm going to check my jar file and look if my xml files are inside. Btw,, I updated my post and put the complete error log.

Comment: I've had a hard time formatting the complete log when I tried putting them in my post. Thus, I decided to put the complete log of my error in this pastebin: https://controlc.com/b2630124

Comment: I fixed it! All I need to do is to remove the <meta> tags in my hbm.xml files.